# api-umbrella log configuration

Tags: nginx, logging, api-umbrella

I'm using api-umbrella on my server, and it works well until I have too many log entries on my server.

So I tried to change the log configuration and log rotation.

1. I found logrotate configuration, and it work well.
2. I try to change
   log configuration for nginx in
   `/opt/api-umbrella/etc/nginx/routeur.conf`  but this config file is ( or seems to be) rewritten each time I restart api-umbrella.

How do I change the configuration for all the api-umbrella elements? Specially nginx?